# Cocos2d-x Crash at setResponseCallback in Android

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

The following code should be a correct cocos2d-x code, and it works on iOS but crashes on Android. I added network permission to AndroidManifest.xml and I do not know how to slove this.

```
HttpRequest* request = new HttpRequest();
request->setUrl(req_url.c_str());
request->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::GET);
request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(ServerSide::onHttpRequestCompleted, this));
HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
request->release();
```

My device has Android 4.4.2

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kona3gxx/kona3g:4.4.2/KOT49H/N5100XXDNK3:user/release-keys'
pid: 21678, tid: 21693, name: Thread-6735  >>> com.zaajle.Battles <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
Stack frame #00  pc 00022fd0  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+15)
Stack frame #01  pc 002ead78  /data/app-lib/com.zaajle.Battles-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (ServerSide::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::network::HttpClient*, cocos2d::network::HttpResponse*)+76): Routine ServerSide::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::network::HttpClient*, cocos2d::network::HttpResponse*) at /Users/azzozhsn/Projects/Battles/proj.android/jni/../../Classes/ServerSide.cpp:59
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out that the error caused by other code inside onHttpRequestCompleted method.